# What's more important for video recording - STM or IS?

Tags: canon, video

As I can see Canon currently lacks native wide (assuming crop sensor) fast prime lenses adopted for video recording that have built-in image stabilization at the same time. As an example, you can either pick Canon EF-S 24mm f/2.8 STM or Canon EF 24mm f/2.8 IS USM, which means you can't enjoy both IS and STM in this case. So my question is, what is generally considered as more "nice to have" and does STM has any other advantages beside being silent?

Comment: If you shoot quality video the camera is normally stabilized anyway (tripod, steadycam...), so IS is irrelevant.

Comment: In line with @xenoid comment - you would probably be using appropriate mics with directional audio capture so USM wouldn't really be an issue